# how to validate for hyphen between spaces using angular pattern

Tags: angular

Should not allow hyphen between two spaces start and end using angular pattern
I have added below code

```
Validators.pattern(/^((?!\s{2,}).)*$/)
```

Above code restricts the spaces but it is not validating start and end spaces
Please help me[image]

Comment: Please post some sample inputs and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Should not allow value **space-space**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer is

```
Validators.pattern(/^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$/)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to match `a hyphen between spaces`, this must be enough:

```
/\s-\s/g
```

This website must be helpful for testing/understanding regex better: https://regex101.com